# doParallel- foreach in R not processing results consistently for every iteration

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel, sink

I am running a large loop in parallel to do regression. The loop was working fine and everything was well but I am suddenly observing very strange a behavior. Some iterations do not reach the step of regression itself. Here's a simple snippet of what I am trying:

```
cl<-makeCluster(14,outfile="")
registerDoParallel(cl)
sink("MajorSink.log")
NG_PSKU=c(1:234)
NG<-foreach(i=NG_PSKU,.multicombine = T,.errorhandling = "pass",.verbose = T) %dopar%
              {
                print(i)
                conn <- file( sprintf(paste0("output_%d.txt") , Sys.getpid()) , open = "a+" )
                sink(conn,append = T)
                cat("NG_PSKU:",i,'\n')
                #regression on NG_PSKU
               }
```

What I observed in the output_%d log files is that the print(i) command was successfully run but cat("NG_PSKU:",i,'\n') was never reached beyond 162nd iteration.

```
[1] 162
NG_PSKU:    162
[1] 163
[1] 164
[1] 165
[1] 166
[1] 167
[1] 168
[1] 169
[1] 170
[1] 171
[1] 172
[1] 173
[1] 174
[1] 175
[1] 176
[1] 177
[1] 178
[1] 179
[1] 180
[1] 181
[1] 182
[1] 183
[1] 184
[1] 185
[1] 186
[1] 187
[1] 188
[1] 189
[1] 190
[1] 191
[1] 192
[1] 193
[1] 194
[1] 195
[1] 196
[1] 197
[1] 198
[1] 199
[1] 200
[1] 201
[1] 202
[1] 203
[1] 204
[1] 205
[1] 206
[1] 207
[1] 208
[1] 209
[1] 210
[1] 211
[1] 212
[1] 213
[1] 214
[1] 215
[1] 216
[1] 217
[1] 218
[1] 219
[1] 220
[1] 221
[1] 222
[1] 223
[1] 224
[1] 225
[1] 226
[1] 227
[1] 228
[1] 229
[1] 230
[1] 231
[1] 232
[1] 233
[1] 234
```

To further investigate I ran the code again with a shorter NG_PSKU (102- 199). To my amazement the code ran successfully. I am left wondering what is happening here. Has anyone else faced a similar situation before? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to combine afterwards?

Comment: @F.Privé by afterwards you mean? I am sorry I don't think I get the full context here..

Comment: I meant: don't use the `.combine` argument (you will get results as a list) and them combine the results based on this list, only once at the end.

Comment: @F.Privé okay but combine was not the only (rather major) problem here. I am concerned on the behavior of the loop execution. Why did the loop not proceed to cat statement (or regression after that).. You have any idea what could be happening there?

Comment: Difficult to say without a fully reproducible example. It could be the combining function so that you try without first and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @F.Privé I tried running the code without combine function and nothing changed. editing my question to remove combine from the scenario..